# SVG in object tag not working as expected in Safari 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, safari

I am trying to put SVG inside an object tag.
It works for all browsers (Including IE) except for Safari 5.
Safari 5 adds scroll bars which cuts the image.

I saw the other posts regarding this issue and I tried the following:

1. Using load event: I tried it, but load is not firing for object tag. If it fires I could use javascript to change the `contentDocument` properties
2. Using CSS rules for SVG tag: Since the SVG is inside the object tag it is not applying.
3. Use Other libraries like JQuery SVG: Well, I tried and it works, but if there is any solution with Object tag that would be nice.

Here is how it looks in IE

[image]

And Here is how it looks for Safari 5 (see the scroll bars)

[image]

Comment: add overflow:hidden to the container?

Comment: It wont work since the container is object tag. I tried that also

Comment: overflow:hidden is supposed to work on an object tag. Report a bug to the webkit bug tracker I guess.

Comment: It is supposed to work, and working in newer versions of Safari. The issue is only with Safari 5